# Regex do not capture group in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I wrote regular expression

```
/translateX\((?<X>-{0,1}\d+)px\)|translateY\((?<Y>-{0,1}\d+)px\)/g
```

For given string

```
translateX(381px) translateY(-94px)
```

To capture `translateX` and `translateY` values. Tested it by regex101.com service, it works well there. But, when I try it in JavaScript  it capture `translateX` value which is `381` but not capture `translateY` which is `-94`. Do you have any ideas why is this happening?

regex101

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nuj5X.png

JavaScript exec

```js
console.log(/translateX\((?<X>-{0,1}\d+)px\)|translateY\((?<Y>-{0,1}\d+)px\)/g.exec("translateX(381px) translateY(-94px)"));
```

Using `matchAll` gives the same result.

JavaScript matchAll

```js
console.log("translateX(381px) translateY(-94px)".matchAll(/translateX\((?<X>-{0,1}\d+)px\)|translateY\((?<Y>-{0,1}\d+)px\)/g).next().value.groups);
```

Comment: Consider adding the JS used into the question as a [mcve]?

Comment: FYI, `{0,1}` is usually written as `?` to indicate an optional pattern.

Comment: You're only calling `.next()` once in the last example, so you only get the first match. Try converting it to an array and you'll get all of the matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just calling `.next()` once, so you only get the first match.
You need to loop over all the results of `.matchAll()`.

```js
for (m of "translateX(381px) translateY(-94px)".matchAll(/translateX\((?<X>-{0,1}\d+)px\)|translateY\((?<Y>-{0,1}\d+)px\)/g)) {
  console.log(m.groups);
}
```

You can also convert the iterator to an array.

```js
console.log([..."translateX(381px) translateY(-94px)".matchAll(/translateX\((?<X>-{0,1}\d+)px\)|translateY\((?<Y>-{0,1}\d+)px\)/g)]
    .map(m => m.groups))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to find both values in one go:

`/translateX\((?<X>-?\d+)px\).*translateY\((?<Y>-?\d+)px\)/g`

```js
console.log(/translateX\((?<X>-?\d+)px\).*translateY\((?<Y>-?\d+)px\)/g.exec("translateX(381px) translateY(-94px)"));
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to write expression that finds translateX and translateY regardless of their position. Like translateX(n) translateY(n) or translateY(n) translateX(n) - which is valid css transform values.